# JQL Query in JIRA filter that sorts my custom type issue first

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I have added a custom issue type called 'Customer problem' in my JIRA installation. When I do a JQL query on a list like this:

```
project = MYPROJECT ORDER BY issuetype ASC
```

The resulting list shows the 'bug' issue type on top, after that my Customer problems and then the rest.

How can I prioritize my own custom issue type over the standard bug issue type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this solved my own question:
[image]

Go to Administration -> Issues -> Issue Type Schemes and click edit. There you'll get a screen which enables you to do exactly what is intended here:
[image]

The proper JQL-query to get the required result is now the one in the question.

Comment: This didn't work in my project, unfortunately. The issue types were still sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following happens: 
ORDER  BY x ASC does order alphabetical. The issuetype "bug" is probably alphabetically in front of your custom issuetype.

A solution with this searchterm could be renamming your custom type to a name with "a_oldname". That brings the name to the front... Not exactly elegant but a workaround.

You could also exclude bugs from the search results:

project = MYPROJECT AND issuetype NOT " bug" ORDER BY issuetype ASC

Alternatively we could try creating a search term that will order things differently... But on a mobile device I currently can't test my thoughts on that...

Comment: We need the bug issuetype also, so filtering it out is not an option. I was hoping that thee is a way to do either an extended query where the sort-order is included or to add something to the issue.

Is it possible to add a field to all issues and to sort on that field?

Comment: yes, you can add custom field and sort on it. Or use one of the existing. For your case Priority is a good candidate. You can add custom priority and set the highest order for it.

Comment: That might work, I'll try that. Do I need to add this field to all possible issue-types? That sounds like a solution that can become hard to maintain.